# Java ME: Problem creating an Image. IOException

Tags: java-me, ioexception

I'm trying to make this chunk of code work:

```
try {
    Image jeton = Image.createImage("bleu.gif");
}
catch(Exception e) {
    system.out.println("exception : "+e)
}
```

An IOException is caught but I don't understand why. Everything seems to be okay with the file ... it's in the src folder with the other .java files. It's also in the build folder with all the other .class files (I'm using netbeans 7.0)

Also, right after the exception is caught, I get this strange message when I run the program:

```
[rms] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for C:\Users\Abdelhamid\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\_delete_notify.dat

[rms] javacall_file_open: _wopen failed for C:\Users\Abdelhamid\javame-sdk\3.0\work\0\appdb\00000002bleu-6gif.tmp
```

Can anybody give me a hand please?

Answer (score 2):

Don't forget to put the slash before image name!

```
Image.createImage("/bleu.gif")
```

Also, **PNG** format is better.